# Display image with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this code to work. Pretty much if the URL has #leaf in it then the  tag updates to display image2.png. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#image").show("fast") {
  // Which anchor is being used?
  switch(window.location.hash) {
     case "#leaf":
       window.location.href = image1.png
     break;
     case "#carrot":
       window.location.href = image2.png
     break;
  }
});
</script>
<a href="#leaf">Leaf</a>
<a href="#carrot">Carrot</a>
<img id="image" />
```

**PS:** I'm open to better ways of achieving this. Just tried the following but still doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#image").show("fast", function() {
    // Which anchor is being used?
    switch(window.location.hash) {
    case "#leaf":
        $(this).attr('src', 'image1.png');
        break;
    case "#carrot":
        $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
        break;
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#leaf">Leaf</a>
<a href="#carrot">Carrot</a>
<img id="image" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser support do you need?  Are you expecting people to share the link with the hash (e.g. *"hey checkout http://example.org#leaf"*)?

Comment: Hmm, your syntax doesn't work. Try $("#image").show("fast", function() { switch ... });

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#image").show("fast", function() {
    // Which anchor is being used?
    switch(window.location.hash) {
    case "#leaf":
        $(this).attr('src', 'image1.png');
        break;
    case "#carrot":
        $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
        break;
  }
});
</script>
<a href="#leaf">Leaf</a>
<a href="#carrot">Carrot</a>
<img id="image" />
```

Setting `window.location.href` sets the location of the current document. You need to set the `src` attribute on your `img` tag. Also, you need to surround your strings with quotes (i.e. `"image1.png"` instead of `image1.png`), or else the JavaScript interpreter will throw an error.

Further, the second argument to the `show` method is a function. You don't have the correct syntax for that, as @Phil-R pointed out.

Comment: The code @Raman posted works for me.  Try these two fiddles (with HASH in the url):  http://jsfiddle.net/dmUgp/6/show/#carrot  http://jsfiddle.net/dmUgp/6/show/#leaf

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro Where are the image files located in relation to your html file? Put this HTML at the end of your file: `<img src="image1.png" />`. If nothing shows up, then the browser can't find your image files, you need to move them.

Comment: Please don't forget to choose the correct answer. And could you update your post to show what error you made? It would help others that might happen upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to declare what means what in your HTML.

```
<a href="#leaf">Leaf</a>
<a href="#carrot">Carrot</a>
<div>
<img data-hash="leaf" src="leaf.jpg" />
<img data-hash="carrot" src="carrot.jpg" />
</div>
```

The JavaScript then just finds images with a matching `data-hash` attribute.

```
function updateImage(){
  var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
  var selector = '[data-hash="{}"]'
                  .replace("{}", hash);
  var $imgs = $('img');
  $imgs.not(selector).fadeOut('fast');
  $imgs.filter(selector).fadeIn('fast');
}

$(window).on('hashchange', updateImage);
updateImage();
```

## [leaf](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2GCL8/2/show/#leaf) or [carrot](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2GCL8/2/show/#carrot)?

Comment: Nothing I've been up for 48 hours and made a mistake in your code

Answer (score 0):

the inital load is never firing. `$("#image").show("fast")` never fires, so it never gets to the switch. Try this instead

```
updateImage = function() {
    var image = $('#image');
    switch(window.location.hash) {
    case "#leaf":
        image.attr('src', 'image1.png');
        break;
    case "#carrot":
        image.attr('src', 'image2.png');
        break;
  }
}
$(window).on('hashchange', updateImage);
```

The only thing needed is to fire it on page load, and you are good to go

Comment: Please elaborate. I'm very new to this. Are you saying I should put an onload="updateImage" attribute in my links?

Comment: no, just that you would need to trigger the updateImage function on pageload. It can be done in by something like `window.onload=function(){hashchange()};` otherwise it will only load the image when you click the link.